# Wordpress multisite with subfolders and relative links

Tags: php, html, wordpress, multisite

I have a Wordpress multisite with subfolders, so that subsite A's path is mydomain.com/subsiteA, and my domain B's path is mydomain.com/subsiteB.

In different Wordpress pages, posts and menus of my first subdomain (subsite A) I am making links to specific slugs and subfolders within the subsite. Let's say for instance mydomain.com/subsiteA/content.
How can I make this links relative to the root of my first subsite? So that when I copy over the pages, posts and menus from subsite A to Subsite B, these will now point to mydomain.com/subsiteB/content, instead of keeping the old path?

I know that by using href="content", I can get to that subfolder with a relative path. The thing is that in some cases I might want this link to work while you are visiting ANOTHER subfolder (let's say images). And the problem with that is that if i keep it like href="images", then the link will bring me to .../content/images, when I actually would want it to go to .../images. In other words I want href="/content" to be pointing to the root of the subsite, instead of pointing to the root of the multisite network.

Hope that I was clear!

Comment: _“In other words I want href="/content" to be pointing to the root of the subsite, instead of pointing to the root of the multisite network.”_ - that is simply not possible. A relative URL starting with a slash means, relative to the _domain_ root, no matter what.

Comment: _“So that when I copy over the pages, posts and menus from subsite A to Subsite B”_ - what exactly does “copying over” look like? There are plugins to help _migrate_ content, such as https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-migrate-db/ - it allows you to _replace_ parts of the database content while creating the database dump, so maybe that is a solution that could help you here.